# react native make part of TextInput to be bold or italics at run time

Tags: react-native, mobile

I have a simple TextInput App like below:

```js
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { textValue: '' };
    this.handleTextInputChange = this.handleTextInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleTextInputChange(input) {
    this.setState({textValue: input})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
         behavior="padding"
         style={{flex:1}}
         enabled>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textInputStyle}
          multiline={true}
          onChangeText={this.handleTextInputChange}
          value={this.state.textValue}
        />
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}
```

What I'd like to do is when I write `##hello` in TextInput, what's instantaneously rendered in TextInput screen is `hello` in bold just like Markdown editing in Dropbox Paper. Similarly, when I write `_hello_`, what I see in the screen is hello italicized.

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qr93.png)

**Can I do that? (Have part of TextInput to have different styles)**

So far, it seems like TextInput can only take one style?

If we cannot have different styles TextInput, what might be an alternative to make part of (some kind of TextInput) bold, italicized, bigger, smaller...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this lib](https://github.com/lappalj4/react-native-easy-markdown) `react-native-easy-markdown` to render markdown text and hide the text input like this and render the markdown component instead. :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Markdown from 'react-native-easy-markdown';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = { text: 'type here ...' };
  onClick = e => {
    this.textInput.focus();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          ref={ref => (this.textInput = ref)}
          style={{ position: 'absolute', left: -1000, top: -1000 }}
          onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text })}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onClick}>
          <Markdown>{this.state.text}</Markdown>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
});
```

here is a demo of the code :

[image: demo of code snippet]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You will lose the cursor and you won't be able to edit text properly (cut, copy, bold etc etc) fyi.

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure you can nest Text within TextInput like this:

```
<TextInput>
    <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}>I'm bold</Text>
</TextInput>
```

Just parse the text and append Text with different styles as needed.

Comment: Maybe this used to work, but it doesn't work in React Native 0.61

Comment: It does work. But beware that onChangeText will give you the raw text (without bold, italic, ..)

Comment: Did you find a solution how to access the formatted text?